# References spilling out of margin in bibliography

Tags: bibtex, horizontal-alignment, line-breaking, citing

I have a search for this problem but all I could find was the case of reference citations in document spilling over, not the bibliography.

Quite simple problem I hope... In my bibliography some of the journal names are spilling over the right margin:

[image: names]

The italic journal names are spilling over, I am using package `cite` and `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}`. I **am** using `\usepackage{microtype}`.

Any idea whats causing this? A MWE of just one article that causes this is,

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

In papers \cite{Ferri2004}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{testbib} 
\end{document}
```

with the bibtex file `testbib.bib` as:

```
@article{Ferri2004,
author = {Ferri, F. and Magatti, D. and Pescini, D. and Potenza, M. a. C. and Giglio, M.},
doi = {10.1103/PhysRevE.70.041405},
file = {},
issn = {1539-3755},
journal = {Physical Review E},
month = oct,
number = {4},
pages = {041405},
title = {{Heterodyne near-field scattering: A technique for complex fluids}},
url = {http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevE.70.041405},
volume = {70},
year = {2004}
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to give us a basic idea of your environment?

Comment: You don't need to use `luainputenc`. LuaTeX expects utf8 encoding.

Comment: It works with `biblatex`. Should be a reason to switch ;-)

Comment: This is a very much cut down version of my thesis for which this problem occurs. I cant remember why I have that in there but I removed it and get no compile errors. Thanks. it still gives me the spilling bibliography though.

Comment: @Johannes_B It is often needed for printing umlauts.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem with my dissertation. The fix for me was loading the `fontspec` package before the `microtype` package. For example:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
```

The `microtype` [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/microtype/microtype.pdf) says:

> With LuaTeX, load `fontspec` before `microtype`.

Answer (score 2):

(Too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer.)

An observation up front: Given that your bibliographic entries have `doi` and `url` fields, you should consider using the `unsrtnat` bibliography style along with the `natbib` citation management package; the venerable `unsrt` style simply ignores those fields. If you load `natbib` with the option `numbers`, you needn't load the `cite` package.

I am able to reproduce the overfull lines if (a) the `microtype` package is loaded and (b) the `unsrt` style is used. I must confess I don't understand what's going with `microtype` here. At any rate, if you want to keep using `microtype` you may want to switch to the `unsrtnat` style (and also load `natbib` instead of `cite`).

Finally, as has already been remarked by @Johannes_B, don't load the `luainputenc` package. When using LuaLaTeX, do make sure that all input files are utf8-encoded.

Answer (score 2):

@OSE's answer solve it for me.

However the more general case is potentially good to disable protrusion before the bibliography -- or any other section it is screwing up.

```
\microtypesetup{protrusion=false}
\bibliography{testbib}
```

Take a look at section 9 of the [microtype manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/microtype/microtype.pdf), turning protrusion off can often be a good thing.

I expect that `\usepackage{fontspec}` before `\usepackage{microtype}` more generally fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

For me the fix was removing this package: `\usepackage{apalike}`

I realize that this isn't included in your project but it helped me when I experienced the exact same issue so I'm sharing for anyone in my same situation.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `\newgeometry` solved the problem.

Something like this:

```
\newgeometry{top=32mm, bottom=27mm, left=40mm,right=15mm}

\bibliography{ref}
```

also you can try this:

```
%SHIFT HORIZONTAL MARGIN ON EVEN/ODD PAGES
\addtolength\oddsidemargin {-1cm}
\addtolength\evensidemargin {-1cm}
\bibliograph
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I started removing packages one by one until it was fixed. In my case it was because of the `{ulem}` package.

I changed the line:

```
\usepackage{ulem}
```

by:

```
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
```

And it worked.