# LuaLaTeX: Load order fontspec, microtype (breaks hyphenation in bibliography)

Tags: biblatex, luatex, fontspec, microtype

The microtype documentation clearly states:

> With LuaTeX, load `fontspec` before `microtype`

However, this breaks hyphenation in some cases in the bibliography, created with biblatex/biber.

The same works with xelatex or if microtype is loaded *before* fontspec.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\usepackage{microtype}


\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}


\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@ARTICLE{test,
  author   = {Doe, John and Doe, Jane and Smith, James},
  title    = {Really Nice English Title},
  journal  = {The Astrophysical Journal},
  langid   = {english},
  year     = {2011},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This produces missing hyphenation with lualatex (Astrophysical is in the margin) but correct hyphenation with xelatex.

If you load microtype before fontspec/polylossia the hyphenation is correct with lualatex as well.

TeXLive 2014, up to date. Tested on Arch and (X)Ubuntu.

- Where does this behaviour come from?
- Should I just ignore the microtype manual and load microtype before fontspec?
- Why does it just happen with lualatex and just in the bibliography?
- bug report to whom? BibLaTeX, Microtype or LuaLaTeX?

Comment: It's quite curious that no `Overfull \hbox` message is shown.

Comment: That left me wondering too.

Comment: Seems very much like a LuaTeX bug.

Comment: Possibly related to [References spilling out of margin in bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196122/references-spilling-out-of-margin-in-bibliography)

Comment: it seems to be fixed in lualatex 0.80.0 distributed in texlive 2015-pretest

Comment: Ah, brilliant. Good, that solves it, I think. Will check tomorrow and you might post it as an answer.

Comment: Most probably the same bug as in [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28733/7674) and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/104447/7674). Great to hear that it has been fixed finally!

Comment: What are the downsides or side effects of loading microtype before fontspec?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like it was a bug in luatex.

This seems to have been fixed in the latest version of luatex, version 0.80.0, as provided in texlive 2015-pretest. Using these versions, the output is as expected:

[image]

Comment: Would you happen to know when this will be included in MiKTeX? I could only find a vague reference to [Summer 2015](http://miktex.org/kb/roadmap-2-9).

Comment: How can I obtain luatex 0.8? The latest released version is 0.79

Comment: @MaxNoe: You can obtain luatex 0.8 from in the TexLive 2015 pretest: https://www.tug.org/texlive/pretest.html. But be aware that this is a *pretest*. It started two days ago. So use it only if you understand the implications. Such a pretest is not for critical documents with time pressure.

Comment: @MaxNoe you need to get the texlive 2015-pretest for that: http://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html . it is however, as the name implies, a prerelease so things may not fully fully working as they should. use at your own risk (i.e., if you are on a tight deadline for something important... don't:-))

Comment: Just installed it and it indeed solves the Problem.