# @mastersthesis' title spilling into the right margin

Tags: biblatex, margins, hyphenation, german

I'm using `@mastersthesis` entries into the `bib` file of my document and I noticed that the title of the `@mastersthesis` entry does not follow the right margin. The title is out of the right margin limit.

I found the following posts, but couldn't fix the error.

[References spilling out of margin in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196122/references-spilling-out-of-margin-in-bibliography)
 [My references to PhD thesis go out of the margins in the bibliography](http://My%20references%20to%20PhD%20thesis%20go%20out%20of%20the%20margins%20in%20the%20bibliography)

Any suggestion, how to limit the `title` of `@mastersthesis` entry within the margin?

Bibliography Output:

[image: Right Margin Error]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=numeric,
sortlocale=de_DE,
natbib=true,
url=true, 
doi=true,
eprint=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@mastersthesis{jan,
title={Analyse der Auswirkungen des Betriebsverhaltens von dezentralen Kraft-W{\"a}rme-gekoppelten Erzeugungseinheiten auf die Energieeffizienz sowie Wirtschaftlichkeit der Anlagen},
author={Jan Teuwsen},
year={2010},
school={Technische Universit{\"a}t Dortmund}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\citet{jan} 
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks like your [`mwe` could be trimmed](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Also, the bib item can be considered too, as a [`mweb`](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography). Also it'd be more clear if you state a direct question. "many related posts and tried many, in the last two hours": "in the last two hours" is unnecessary info. Related posts? You can specify.

Comment: I have specified the posts but I'm not sure if it wasn't direct enough to understand the question. @nilon

Comment: @ArslanYousaf compiling your MWE it looks alright to me, could you check your MWE illustrates your problem and if so it may be helpful to post a picture of the output to highlight which part of the output you object to.

Comment: note that your document hasn't specified a language so will be trying to hyphenate that as English, which clearly it isn't, you might want to locally set a language or add some `\-` to the bib file `Wirt\-schaft\-lich\-keit` or whever appropriate breaks are

Comment: It compiles normally on my system. However, the thesis title is *not* in italic.

Comment: I had a full `\documentclass` package, which was also including `ngerman` definition. But our other friends insisted to make `mwe` short and I then removed it and used `article` class without further details. @DavidCarlisle

Comment: @ArslanYousaf - Providing the option `ngerman` at the document class stage is of little use unless the `babel` package is loaded as well -- which isn't the case, at least not in the MWE you posted.

Comment: `ngerman` passed as an option to `article` would not do anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you add the instruction

```
\hyphenation{wirt-schaft-lich-keit}
```

to the preamble. Evidently, left to its own devices, TeX doesn't know how to hyphenate this word. This isn't all that surprising, really, as the system's default language is English, not German.

[image]

If you omit the instruction `\hyphenation{wirt-schaft-lich-keit}`, the full word will be placed on line two, just as in your screenshot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@mastersthesis{jan,
  title={Analyse der Auswirkungen des Betriebsverhaltens von 
  dezentralen Kraft-W{\"a}rme-gekoppelten Erzeugungseinheiten 
  auf die Energieeffizienz sowie Wirtschaftlichkeit der 
  Anlagen},
  author={Jan Teuwsen},
  year={2010},
  school={Technische Universit{\"a}t Dortmund},
}
\end{filecontents}

\hyphenation{wirt-schaft-lich-keit}

\usepackage[textwidth=5.25in]{geometry} % educated guess...
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=numeric,
sortlocale=de_DE,
natbib=true,
url=true, 
doi=true,
eprint=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*} 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mico 
Can I define `\hyphenation` the way I want? And will this work for `url` entries?

Comment: @ArslanYousaf - Not entirely sure what you mean by "the way I want". The macro expects a list of space-separated words, where each permissible hyphenation point is indicated by a `-`. E.g., `\hyphenation{be-dwarf obst-feld gott-lieb heath-row  wirt-schaft-lich-keit}`. (The words in this list are all examples where TeX either can't find the correct hyphenation points -- the first three words -- or finds none at all -- the final two.) BTW, if you do load the `babel` package, be sure to provide the `\hyphenation` instruction *after* loading `babel`.

Comment: @ArslanYousaf - `\hyphenation` will most definitely not operate on the contents of a `\url` directive.

Comment: I meant by "the way I want" like we can write for any word, as long as we follow the `\hyphenation` syntax. I actually have another citation in my bibliography, which is out of the margin, and its from `url` entry. I tried the way you suggested for `@mastersthesis` entry but does not work for `url`.

Comment: @ArslanYousaf - Are you loading the `url` package with the options `hyphens`, `spaces`, and `obeyspaces`? If not, do give it a try.